# how can I build a orderbook API in our database

Tags: 0x

I read 0x project, but have some confused. I want to build a orderbooks in our database, but know seem like we just call the 0x orderbook API? that is mean the order data in your service right? I just have this confused. I will appricate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For background, after a 0x order is created, it can be  shared with counter-parties in a variety of ways, submitting it to our orderbook is just one way. For a list of other ways to share an order, checkout the ["How does 0x work?" section](https://docs.0x.org/introduction/introduction-to-0x#how-does-0x-work).

You are correct that 0x API does host an orderbook of 0x Limit Orders so anyone can easily provide liquidity to or take liquidity from it (docs for how to use our orderbook are found [here](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-orderbook/introduction)); however, it is also  possible to create your own orderbook if you choose not to use ours, since the project is [open-sourced](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api).